# When creating a div dynamically, the children number is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I have a problem and I can't find any solution.
When I click on a button, it creates a `div` with input and another button as a children.
At the first and second click no error occurs.
But at the third click an error happens.It creates the third `div` but it multiples the children of the first `div`
and in the fourth click it adds another child to the first and second `div`.
I want it to creat a normal number of divs and children.

There is my code. Try it to see the problem .

```js
var secondContainer = $(".second-container");
var input1 = $('<input class="bot-section border border-secondary" type="text" name="" value="" disabled>');
var button1 = $('<button class="remove-btn btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" name="button">-</button>');
var add = 1;

$("#adding-btn").click(function() {
  let newDiv = $("#second-container").last().append('<div class="new"></div>');
  $(".new").append(input1);
  $(".new").append(button1);
});
```

```css
.my {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
  font-size: 3.7rem;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-family: 'Kufam', sans-serif;
  padding:10px;
  border:0;
  box-shadow:0 0 15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  width: 35%!important;
}

.inpt {
  margin: 35px auto 8px -3px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #1A1A40;
  color: white;
  /* padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px; */
}

#adding-btn {
  margin-top: -3px!important;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* the section will be added */

.bot-section {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  color: black;
}

.remove-btn {
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>to do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Kufam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="my">My to do list</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-section">
      <input id="inputField" class="inpt" type="text" name="" value="">
      <button id="adding-btn"  class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="button">+</button>
    </div>
    <div id="second-container">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
$(".new").append
```

it selects all `.new` in the document, not just the newly added one.

Equally, when you use `$(selector).append(...` it returns the selector, not the new div.

You can create the div first, or you can change `.append(..new..)` to `$(..new..).appendTo` and it will return the newly created div, so that you could either chain or append to only that new div

```
$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  let newDiv = $('<div class="new"></div>');
  $("#second-container").last().append(newDiv);
  newDiv.append(input1);
  newDiv.append(button1);
});
```

```
$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  let newDiv = $('<div class="new"></div>').appendTo($("#second-container").last());
  newDiv.append(input1);
  newDiv.append(button1);
});
```

In addition, you are pre-creating your sub-elements with

```
var input1 = $("...html...");
var button1 = $("...html...");
```

these will create a *single* element (for each), so when you use `.append(input1)` it will *move* the element into the new `newDiv`.

You can see this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5p2x3f1/1/), where each new `.new` is a red box and the inputs move to the last container each time instead of creating new ones.

You could clone() these each time

```
newDiv.append(input1.clone())
```

but the simpler solution is to not create these as nodes (in memory) in the first instance and instead use plain html.

Updated snippet:

```js
var secondContainer = $(".second-container");
var input1 = '<input class="bot-section border border-secondary" type="text" name="" value="" disabled>';
var button1 = '<button class="remove-btn btn btn-outline-danger " type="button" name="button">-</button>';
var add = 1;

$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  let newDiv = $('<div class="new"></div>');
  $("#second-container").last().append(newDiv);
  newDiv.append(input1);
  newDiv.append(button1);
});
```

```css
.my{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
  font-size: 3.7rem;
}


.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  width: 35%!important;
}


#adding-btn{
  margin-top: -3px!important;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* the section will be added */

.remove-btn{
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Kufam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <h1 class="my">My to do list</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top-section">
        <input id="inputField" class="inpt" type="text" name="" value="">
        <button id="adding-btn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="button">+</button>
      </div>
      <div id="second-container">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Additional note, will need to use *event delegation* for your remove button.

Comment: when i apply ur code it creates only 1 div and i can't add more

Comment: apologies, didn't spot how you were pre-creating input1/button1 instead of using html.  One sec to update.

Comment: i fix it thx for help :)